Office.ribbon.requestUpdate throws SharedRuntime ID missing error
I am trying to develop an excel addin using Office JS Api and Angular. I want to achieve enable/disable ribbon controls functionality in desktop version.
when I use Office.ribbon.requestUpdate method it throws ERROR RichApi.Error: The Sharedruntime ID is missing.
I followed steps shown in this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands

Platform : Windows
Host : Excel
Office JS Api - angular desktop


This is the error I am getting in console

Did you follow the steps in Shared Runtime required?

I have multiple controls when I use same id for action.sourceLocation it works, but I want to open different html file on different control click at that time it is throwing same error, any idea how to solve that one.

You need to provide a lot more detail. I don't know what you mean by "action.sourceLocation" of "different html file on different control click".

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/4368 here I have my manifest what I am trying to convey is one of my controls has different sourceLocation resId in action.sourcelocation and after opening taskpane from that control I want to enable and disable other controls but it throws error of sharedRuntimeID missing, it only enables and disables from runtime resId, so I want a way to have enable/disable functionality with taskpane opened from other resId sourceLocation control as well cause different controls sourcelocation is redirect to different url/components, Is there a way to get that
